# Prevent word wrap in error message

Tags: firefox, extjs, extjs4

I have weird situation that extjs 4 always puts last word of custom error message in new row, and effectively hides it. I tried shortening message, but always last word goes to new line. **This happens in Firefox 7.0.1 (firebug turned off), not in Chrome, Opera, Safari.**

Default message text is displayed correctly. My error message has no strange letters or symbols.

I tried escaping white characters, putting nobr tags etc... but nothing works.

How to prevent this behavior?

I have no any css or any other styling applied. Here is code from view:

```
this.items = [{
            waitMsgTarget: 'dailyReport',
            xtype: 'form',
            url: 'php/dailyReport.php',
            items: [{
                margin: 10,
                xtype: 'datefield',
                name: 'reportDate',
                fieldLabel: 'Report for',
                format: 'd.m.Y.',
                altFormats: 'd.m.Y|d,m,Y|m/d/Y',
                value: getCorrectDate(),
                disabledDays: [0]
            },
            {
                margin: 10,
                xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                fieldLabel: 'Report by',
                columns: 2,
                vertical: true,
                allowBlank: false,
                blankText: 'Choose at least one.',
                items: [{
                    boxLabel: 'pos',
                    name: 'rb',
                    inputValue: '1',
                    checked: true
                },
                {
                    boxLabel: 'seller',
                    name: 'rb',
                    inputValue: '2',
                    checked: true
                }]
            }]
        }];
```

Comment: can you post some code, or screenshots, and what version of extjs are you using ...?

Comment: any extra css you've added to the project?

Comment: I have updated question. I didn't add any other css.

Comment: Your code does not show how and where your custom error message is created/shown. We need a bit more of your code to help you.

Comment: @suknic blankText: 'Choose at least one.', causes error to appear if no checkbox option is selected

Comment: @Milan I am sorry, I did not see the blank text as error message, my fault. By the way, I tested the code you posted and got a clean one-liner blank text. No wrapping at all. What browser do you use?

Comment: Firefox 6.0.2 and 7.0.1 are causing problem. Chrome, Opera, Safari - OK.

Comment: I tested in FF7 without problems, maybe you are overnesting. This code works for me: [http://jsfiddle.net/pJnZH/](http://jsfiddle.net/pJnZH/) Please try this and if it does work for you, some other part of your code is causing it, if it does not work for you, it could eventually be a problem with one of your browser addons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Ctrl' + '+' was reason. My view in Firefox was zoomed in, but I didn't notice it until today. After I returned it to normal zoom level 'Ctrl' + '0' everything works and shows up fine. Silly me, it took me 2 weeks to realize this.